# How to uninstall Boost 1.55 with Visual studio?

Tags: visual-c++, boost

I just installed `Boost 1.55` prebuilt binaries; however, it conflicts with `Eigen 3.20`; and always causes error like this:

```
 Eigen\array(8): fatal error C1189: #error :  
 The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. 
 All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core.
```

How can I completely remove Boost from my computer? Can I delete the boost installation folder only since there is no such item in the Windows Add/remove program list?

Comment: Yes, you can just delete the whole boost tree, but make sure that boost headers/binaries were not copied to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall only the Boost libraries (not the product):

1. Open the Windows Control Panel.
2. Choose Uninstall a program.
3. Double-click Boost Libraries for C++Builder . The Boost installer starts.
4. On the Welcome page of the Boost installer, choose the Remove option and click Next.
5. On the Ready to Uninstall page, click Next.

[More details](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Boost_Libraries#Installing_and_Uninstalling_the_Boost_Libraries)

Comment: thank you . As mentioned, there is no such an item in the installed program list however.

Comment: Then you can delete the folders, make sure that you have reverted the changes made for installation. Check the above link for more details.

Comment: It seems the installation only "extracting" files into a folder and does not maker any other changes. thanks